# logging line number in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, exception

I'm currently working on logging errors in a procedure. The goal of this procedure is to be called upon in exception handlers in the other packages in the DB and log the errors that each program encounters. below is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APMS.test_procedure AS

    procedure write_error_log (errcode number, errstr varchar2) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction; 
    -- this procedure stays in its own new private transaction
    begin                         
          INSERT INTO error_log
               (ora_err_tmsp,
                      ora_err_number,
                      ora_err_msg,
                      ora_err_line_no)
          values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  errcode,
                  errstr,
                  'line number');
          COMMIT;  -- this commit does not interfere with the caller's transaction.
    end write_error_log;

 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mockdata
        VALUES ('data1', 'mockname', 'mockcity'); 

  exception when others then             
    write_error_log(sqlcode,sqlerrm);
    raise; 
 END test_procedure;
/
```

I'm currently just inducing an error in my mock_data table to log the error in the error_log table and see if  its functional I just cant figure out how to log the line number column. I'm a complete beginner so any help would appreciated. Addiotionally, If anybody knows how I would be able to use this procedure in other packages/procedures to log the errors in other packages that would be awesome as well. I'm here to learn so any feedback is appreciated, I can further expand on this post if i'm not being clear.

Comment: I use this package from Steven Feurstein. Apparently not available from Toad anymore but can be found here http://awads.net/wp/2007/08/08/new-oracle-plsql-error-management-framework-released/   Why write it when you can use an established package?

Comment: Thanks for the resources, unfortunately, I'm using Toad and my superior would like me to learn and write up the procedure for other programs to run in their exception handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`. You can look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-jan/o25plsql-093886.html) for more information.

Something like this should make works your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APMS.test_procedure AS

    procedure write_error_log (errcode number, errstr varchar2,errline varchar2) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction; 
    -- this procedure stays in its own new private transaction
    begin                         
          INSERT INTO error_log
               (ora_err_tmsp,
                      ora_err_number,
                      ora_err_msg,
                      ora_err_line_no)
          values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  errcode,
                  errstr,
                  errline);
          COMMIT;  -- this commit does not interfere with the caller's transaction.
    end write_error_log;

 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mockdata
        VALUES ('data1', 'mockname', 'mockcity'); 

  exception when others then             
    write_error_log(sqlcode,sqlerrm,DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
    raise; 
 END test_procedure;
```

Comment: I tried writing that in the values section as well as the exception handler ... kept getting errors. Although I will do some more reading up. It's possible I'm just using it incorrectly.

Comment: played around with that utility, awesome, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to get the call stack:

- **dbms_utility.format_error_stack**
- **dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace**

For example,

```
SQL> declare
  2    v1 integer := 1;
  3    v2 integer := 0;
  4    v3 integer;
  5    procedure p1 (v1 in integer, v2 in integer, v3 out integer) is 
  6    begin 
  7      v3 := v1 / v2;
  8    end;
  9    procedure p2 (v1 in integer, v2 in integer, v3 out integer) is 
 10    begin 
 11      p1 (v1, v2, v3);
 12    end;
 13  begin
 14    p2 (v1, v2, v3);
 15  exception
 16    when others then
 17      dbms_output.put_line ('---------------------');
 18      dbms_output.put_line ('This is what you record in log table:');
 19      dbms_output.put (dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
 20      dbms_output.put (dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
 21      dbms_output.put_line ('---------------------');
 22      raise;
 23  end;
 24  /
---------------------
This is what you record in log table:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 7
ORA-06512: at line 11
ORA-06512: at line 14
---------------------
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 22
```